# How to always refresh global parameters from another script in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, spyder

**script1.py** stores all the parameters, which I want to change quite often:

```
a, b = 10, 15
```

**script2.py** loads and do something with it

```
from script1 import *
out = a + b
```

The problem is, when I change values of *a* or *b* in the first script and rerun the second script, their values often don't update. I guess the module *script1* is not reloaded.

I read about *importlib.reload(module)* but not sure how to do import * with it. I have many parameters so am really keen not to have to do script1.a and so on.

If there are other better ways to manage global parameters in a separate script, I'll be interested in that too.

Comment: If you truly rerun the second script, then it necessarily needs to reimport `script1`. Are you sure you are saving `script1.py` first?

Comment: For sure I did. It seems to me that Python doesn't always reload the modules if they have already been imported before in the same session. I can restart the kernel, but that takes too much time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rerun the second script"? To me, that implies a kernel restart, because you are starting a new interpreter to parse, compile, and execute the script.

Comment: Correction: I do 'run cell' in the second script. When I do 'run', I actually had an error: TypeError: handle_get_file_code() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_all', but I guess that is a spyder-specific problem.

Comment: There appears to be a *lot* of critical details missing from your question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details - I hesitate to elaborate on the latest error when I do 'run' as it  seems to be a separate issue from the main question. But assuming 'run cell' on a script without cells is identical to 'run', then I still have the problem that the kernel is not restarted every time. Unless 'run cell' and 'run' indeed do different things.

Comment: I'm not even sure I know what you mean by "run" and "run cell". Is that a Jupyter thing?

Comment: It's a Spyder thing. 'Run' (F5) would run the whole script, and here I just discovered today would trigger an error for any script (so the problem is not related to above question). I've been using 'Run cell (ctrl return)' - in Spyder you could divide the script into different cells, and run each separately. But my script has no cell divisions, so I figure it should be identical to running the whole script. And here the imported modules are certainly not refreshed each time I run it.

Comment: I've added the `spyder` tag, as this question isn't really relevant to Python in general.